# How to remove an Azure role assignment from a managed identity?

Tags: azure

In the Azure role assignments section of a managed identity there is only a button to add role assignments. There doesn't appear to be a way to remove a role assignment once it's been added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The role assignment can be removed as you would remove role assignments to other principal types. In the Portal, navigate to the scope where the role assignment was created, and use the Access Control (IAM) menu to find and remove the assignment. Azure CLI or PowerShell could also be used.

Comment: It takes A LONG time to show up in the portal. I think it took nearly an hour to show up in IAM, and only a moment to add.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Role I went to the resource group, then to Access Control (IAM), Roles tab, then clicked View against the Contributor role, then to the Assignments tab, and was then able to click the trash can button against the user I was looking to modify.